# PDFBox: How to draw text on top of a filled rectangle?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to use Java with PDFBox to draw some text to a PDF file, and set a background color for the text.  I know how to draw text and draw filled rectangles, but when I try to draw text in the same position as a rectangle, the text is never shown.  Example:

```
//draw rectangle
content.setNonStrokingColor(200, 200, 200); //gray background
content.fillRect(cursorX, cursorY, 100, 50);

//draw text
content.setNonStrokingColor(0, 0, 0); //black text
content.beginText();
content.setFont(family, fontPt);
content.moveTextPositionByAmount(cursorX, cursorY);
content.drawString("Test Data");
content.endText();
```

The text never shows up. It is always covered by the rectangle. Any ideas for how to make the text draw on top of the rectangle?

EDIT: As Mkl mentioned in answer, the code I provided actually works. My problem ended up being that the code was in a loop, drawing the background for each line, but the background was drawing over the previous line, and not the current line, overwriting previous text. I just needed to alter the order of events in my looping. Should this question be deleted? It seems unlikely that anyone else would find it useful.

Comment: did you close the content stream?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The accepted answer just helped me find a bug in my code.  You never know when some random old answer will be helpful, in my opinion the question should be kept.

Comment: With 7 upvotes, the answer has proven to be useful 

Answer (score 12):

The code you show works.

I made it runnable like this:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
document.addPage(page);
PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

int cursorX = 70;
int cursorY = 500;

//draw rectangle
content.setNonStrokingColor(200, 200, 200); //gray background
content.fillRect(cursorX, cursorY, 100, 50);

//draw text
content.setNonStrokingColor(0, 0, 0); //black text
content.beginText();
content.setFont(font, 12);
content.moveTextPositionByAmount(cursorX, cursorY);
content.drawString("Test Data");
content.endText();

content.close();
document.save(new File("textOnBackground.pdf"));
document.close();
```

*([DrawOnBackground.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/DrawOnBackground.java))*

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Thus, the cause for your issue lies beyond the code you provided.

**PS**: I use PDFBox 1.8.10.